# How CartoDB is able to add mouse interaction over PNG image Tiles

Tags: leaflet, mapnik, cartodb

I am new to GIS mapping.

I wonder how CartoDB is able to add mouse interaction like(mouse Hover/click) on The generated PNG image tiles. Can anyone explain the background process about how its done. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very nice question!

They use a custom implementation of the [UTF-GRID specification](https://github.com/mapbox/utfgrid-spec/blob/master/1.3/utfgrid.md) called [Zera](https://github.com/CartoDB/zera).

You can read a very good explanation [here](https://blog.mapbox.com/how-interactivity-works-with-utfgrid-3b7d437f9ca9).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is https://github.com/CartoDB/zera, which implements https://github.com/mapbox/utfgrid-spec

Comment: Hhhmm, that plugin is not listed in https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html , it might be worth to add it to that list.